# Is there a way to move recycledView item to the bottom when click on it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

When Item clicked I want it to go to the bottom of the recycled view - I mean to make it the last item (my adapter extends **Firestore**RecyclerAdapter). How can i do it ?

I wrote a working onClickListener. Now I am trying to find out how can I move it to the bottom.

I already search in google and here for answer with no success.

**(*Without* remove it from firestore and add it back)**

Comment: Do you want to MOVE the item to the bottom of the list, or do you want to SCROLL the recyclerView? If you want to MOVE it, you'll need to have the data locally mutated so the item is now last. If you want to scroll the list, I'm sure you have read about the various `scroll` methods available to scroll a recyclerview.

Comment: change its position by ONE click on it. (change the order of items in the recycler)

Comment: I am trying to build a todo list using firestore and recycledview , so when user click on item it will move down (to be the last item) and its color will be changed. I dont know how to change the position. tnx :)

Comment: Have you try notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition).

Comment: tnx :) so easy yet waste so much time on it . TNX @KasımÖzdemir !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION IS (Base on **@KasımÖzdemir** comment)

If you would like to change item(Swap items) position in RecyclerView from current_position to target_position you should use: (RecyclerView  Adapter method)

```
notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
```

Read [More](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)